# How to send notifications (FCM) using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an API and I want to send a notification to the smartphone when I alter something in a table called Meeting. For that I am creating a method of type POST where I send the following **JSON Body** with also the Authorization key(provided by firebase) and to the following URL ***https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send***.

```
@Headers -> *******



 {
       "to": "/topics/groupNameChoosenByYou",
       "data": {
          "title": "Your title",
          "message": "Your message"
       }
    }
```

This is my AndroidPushNotificationsService

```
@Service
public class AndroidPushNotificationsService {

    private static final String FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY = "AAAAq88vWWE:APA91bF5rSyqGbx26AY5jm6NsEfwJynQsnTd1MPFOTOz1ekTGZyof3Vz6gBb0769MLLxD7EXMcqKiPIHnqLh5buHEeUASnpsn-ltxR1J8z3kWJIAPNWlPZB0r0zKkXMyWkrbT3BLPWmCdi-NZnP3Jkb2z-QqtwJt5Q";
    private static final String FIREBASE_API_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> send(HttpEntity<String> entity) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Authorization", "key=" + FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY));
        interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

        String firebaseResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(FIREBASE_API_URL, entity, String.class);

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(firebaseResponse);
    }
}
```

This is my HeaderRequestInterceptor

```
public class HeaderRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private final String headerName;
    private final String headerValue;

    public HeaderRequestInterceptor(String headerName, String headerValue) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
        this.headerValue = headerValue;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {
        HttpRequest wrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
        wrapper.getHeaders().set(headerName, headerValue);
        return execution.execute(wrapper, body);
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    private final String TOPIC = "test";

    @Autowired
    AndroidPushNotificationsService androidPushNotificationsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> send() throws JSONException {

        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        body.put("to", "/topics/" + TOPIC);
        body.put("priority", "high");

        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        notification.put("title", "JSA Notification");
        notification.put("body", "Happy Message!");

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("Key-1", "JSA Data 1");
        data.put("Key-2", "JSA Data 2");

        body.put("notification", notification);
        body.put("data", data);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body.toString());

        CompletableFuture<String> pushNotification = androidPushNotificationsService.send(request);
        CompletableFuture.allOf(pushNotification).join();

        try {
            String firebaseResponse = pushNotification.get();

            return new ResponseEntity<>(firebaseResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Push Notification ERROR!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I go to `http://localhost:8080/springbootapi/send`I get a 404, but the server is running. I wanted to know if everything is ok with the code I have, because FCM api requires a POST method, and in my /send method I am doing a GET, so basically I am creating an API to call other api in order to provide notifications to users when tables are altered thats the main purpose. Is there a better way to do this our is even a good practice?

Comment: Please make sure you are entering the correct URL. 404 is usually a page not found error/path error, since you are doing only rest it must be a path problem. Make sure you don't have any path prefix between the 'port' and your '@RequestMapping' (in this case '/send').

Comment: The context path is empty. The project was a jar but i put it as a war is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

FCM requires POST and you are sending POST in restTemplate. It doesnt matter if your controller is GET or even DELETE. 
But ofc you should make it POST since you are sending something, not retrieving. 
404 means you are entering wrong URL. It should be:
http://localhost:8080/send (if you are using 8080 port)

Comment: I repetead the proccess and try as you said..it does not work, 404 is still here :/

Comment: You have 404 from your Controller or Firebase?

Comment: 404 in my controller. The context path is empty. The project was a jar but i put it as a war is that a problem?

Comment: No, war is not a problem. 
Check your Java classes. Maybe you have some Configuration class which is changing your base URL. 

Look for that Bean: 
@Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping()

Or by implementing EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
And changing  Override
 public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container)
Or in properties
server.contextPath=/???

Answer (score 1):

Below the `@RestController` annotation add `@RequestMapping("/springbootapi")` or Whatever path you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not set any context path to the spring boot application`(Check log and search for Context path which might defined in Application.yml/properties)`

If you are getting 404 then port 8080 is perfectly fine but make sure that the port opened by your Spring boot application only`(check the spring boot printed logs in console for port also)`.

What i believe from you question is, the 404 error is not because of FCM but with the application you are running in your machine.

Comment: The context path is empty. The project was a jar but i put it as a war is that a problem?

Comment: Are you able to see in log something like this ?  `Mapped "{[/send],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}",......` If not then the rest controller is not scanned by spring boot

Comment: : Mapped "{[/send],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>

Comment: that appears :/